# FIS-B Product Registry Location

Tags: usa, ads-b

I'm a software engineer that's interested in decoding raw FIS-B data. DO-267A (E.1) points me at http://fpr.tc.faa.gov/default.asp as the location of the FIS-B Product Registry. However, I have been unable to connect to this website the last 2 days. Does anyone know if this is still the correct site? Is the data hosted anywhere else?

Answer (score 1):

I have been unable to determine if the Product Registry has been formally relocated or replaced. However, I was able to find all of the relevant information in DO-358A. It wouldn't surprise me if this has become the de facto Product Registry, replacing the FAA website.